# how to send back acknowledge message to html by php

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

I'm a beginner in HTML and PHP. I made an HTML file include a form that sends variables with POST format to a PHP file for process and validation. In addition this form sends a picture file.

But really I confused that this PHP file how send back acknowledge for show to user.
For more description I want design an HTML form that send values to PHP and finally show user "thank you message" if the image size and format is valid or show "unable to upload your image" in first html form. Is it possible??
Regards...

Comment: if the PHP is generating the HTML, why not just implement `if` inside the PHP code based on the "validity" of the data? or basically have you read PHP's tutorial and examples?

Answer (score 2):

HTML is static stuff. It sends nor validates anything. The HTML describes what a page should look like and if there are special elements, like your form. It is the blueprint that a browser uses to render a page.

The browser *can* communicate with a server. The browser can send a *request* to the server, and the server sends a *response* in return.

The request consists of a *URL* and optionally extra data, like POSTed form data.

The server normally always sends a reponse, unless something goes wrong (in terms of connection loss or a time-out). Even in case of a server error, you will often still get a response).

So, since you got a php script that processes the form data, it is its reponsibility to send a reponse that tells you, the user of the browser, whether posting has failed or succeeded.

The response is loaded and displayed by the browser as a new page, so after sending the form, the browser will render the response it got, which might contain an error message or a thank you message, and if you like, a new form to upload another file.

After that, there's also the possibility to post forms using AJAX. Then, you can get the response in the background (asynchonously) and add it to the existing page. But that's a whole new chapter, and I think you should try the normal way first.

Answer (score 0):

```
        After process your Post data use
       use this code on that page :-
      header('Location: http://www.example.com?msg="success"');
     and on that side use that code
     if(isset($_GET['msg'])){echo $_GET['msg']//or show what ever you want like you               message in echo ;})
```